# Custom OptionalAttribute with Ninject

Tags: c#, .net, inversion-of-control, ninject

Is there a way that I can create my own `OptionalAttribute` for Ninject?

I know I can replace `InjectAttribute` by using the `NinjectSettings` class (which I already have done), but there doesn't seem to be any option for the `OptionalAttribute`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, I'm afraid there isn't.

Optional dependencies should not be used in most cases anyway. Consider to create a Null Object (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern) of the dependency instead.

Comment: could you put this on your road map?

Comment: @DanielA.White Why not fork it and add it yourself? Maybe they'll integrate it with a pull request.

Comment: @DanielA.White Can confirm I've had great experiences with pull requests on ninject